# Odata v4 web api 2.2 context is not currently tracking the entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

working on an end point using c# - trying to add a role to a user (boilerplate .NET user tables)
trying to determine correct way to update relationship table.

```
var context =new WebClient.Default.OptimizedContextContainer(new Uri("service_hostUri"));
context.Format.UseJson();

User userToUpdate = context.User.ByKey(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "userId", Guid.Parse("some_guid" } }).GetValue();

Role roleToAdd = context.Role.ByKey(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "roleId", Guid.Parse("some_guid" } }).GetValue();

userToUpdate.Roles.Add(roleToAdd);
context.UpdateObject(userToUpdate.Roles);

context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

code fails on UpdateObject call to update users roles - 'The Context is not currently tracking the entity' -If I eliminated the UpdateObject call and just use saveChangesAsAsync there is no error, but the role is not added
how can I add a role to a user in this fashion?

Answer (score 1):

With navigation properties that are collections you should use

```
AddToObject(userToUpdate,"Roles",RoleToAdd)
```

instead of

```
context.UpdateObject(userToUpdate.Roles);
```

and remove

```
userToUpdate.Roles.Add(roleToAdd);
```